# How SignIn Card works compared to HeroCard

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm using HeroCard with Microsoft BotBuilder and it works fine.

Now, I'm also using SignIn Card but I don't understand how it works compared to HeroCard. Messenger display a card with a text and a button. Clicking on the button will open the associated URL.

According to this question it's only the UI
[Bot Framework - Sign-In Card, how get auth result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080683/bot-framework-sign-in-card-how-get-auth-result)

- Any NodeJS sample to implement a Sign-In callback ?
- I thought it would use at least WebViews ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question about Node and Sign-in, take a look to the [Node AuthBot version](https://github.com/CatalystCode/node-authbot). There you will find the documentation and how to start with the package.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [out](https://blog.vjrantal.net/2016/11/15/facebook-account-linking-with-microsoft-bot-framework/).

That's an example to link your customers accounts to your bot. The best solution for messenger channel. And it is easy to implement.

HeroCard and SignInCard are two different types of cards. 
Hero card is more likely if you want to show some data. You may use this if you want to show one single large picture with buttons(options).

In Bot Framework [docs](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/) you can find more cards.