# How to Authenticate MS Teams User Against Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework

I am trying to create a bot which would be deployed into MS Teams (and Skype for Business). I see when a user interacts with the bot they are provided with a `channelData.tenant.id` and the Bot Framework docs say that this is the "The tenant ID for the user." I was wondering if I can use this (or another piece of information coming from the inbound message) to authenticate the user against my Azure AD? Also, would this require me to authenticate the user via an authentication flow like is done with the AuthBot?(https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot)

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you add more details on what you would like to do with your authenticated user?

Comment: @NicolasR I provided some clarification below. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Take a look at my answer that answers this same question here:
[How to Authenticate a user against Windows AD using username and password of his computer in Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080683/bot-framework-sign-in-card-how-get-auth-result/46918343#46918343)

Comment: You can see my answer to this same question here: [Authenticate a user with username and password against Windows Active Directory using Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080683/bot-framework-sign-in-card-how-get-auth-result/46918343#46918343)

Answer (score 0):

You have the `tenant.id` provided in `channelData` yes, so you could use it to make some customs requests like with Graph API.

**For MS Teams**, you can also get more information by calling `GetConversationMembersAsync` and call `AsTeamsChannelAccount` method on the members that you got (this method is included in `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams` NuGet package)

Sample:

```
// Fetch the members in the current conversation
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(context.Activity.ServiceUrl));
var members = await connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(context.Activity.Conversation.Id);

// Concatenate information about all the members into a string
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var member in members.Select(m => m.AsTeamsChannelAccount()))
{
    sb.AppendLine($"GivenName = '{member.Name}', Email = '{member.Email}', User Principal Name '{member.UserPrincipalName}', AAD ObjectId '{member.ObjectId}', TeamsMemberId = '{member.Id}'");
}

// Post the member info back into the conversation
await context.PostAsync($"People in this conversation: {sb.ToString()}");
```

With this call you will have additional interesting values: `Email` and `ObjectId` (which is the user's Azure AD object ID).

As a conclusion, you still have to log your user if you need to do some authenticated logic, but in MS Teams case you have more information and ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. All I really am trying do is validate who the user is when they engage with the bot and it seems that with a combination of `Email` and `ObjectId` I could do that. I was wondering if you knew if there is an equivalent package to `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams` in NodeJS? Or if perhaps you knew how I could use the `tenant.id` or some other piece of information in the user's session object to authenticate them?

Comment: the tenant Id is only the Id of your Azure AD tenant (for example your company tenant), it is not linked to a specific user. If you want to authenticate the user, you will have to ask him...

For the package, yes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-teams
And documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/bots1on1