# Authenticate microsoft Chatbot on bases of existing website Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, botframework, chatbot

I'm creating a chat bot for my existing web application that is develop using MVC5 ASP.NET C#. 
If the user login in my existing web application then my bot should not ask for authentication or don't need to verify user and the conversation should start with Hello MK.
as i'm new to microsoft chatbot i want to various way so authenticate user like
1.If i can use QueryString
2.Cookies etc. any tutorials or link could be much helpful.

Comment: Great question, I am doing what you are asking in [this project](https://github.com/JasonSowers/ChatHistoryBot-Public)  feel free to take a look and see if it gets you closer to a solution.  Note the project was centered around saving and displaying chat history in the web chat control so there will be a lot of code you do not need to use.

Comment: Feel free to check out my answer to a similar question to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46918343/7177029

Comment: @JasonSowers thank you for this project,but my question is how can get LoggedIn UserName to be displayed as 'WelCome User'.and one more thing if i'm using DirectLine Channel then is it possible to send Some Extra Properties to model and access in MessageController.cs on ConversationUpdate.

Comment: basically i want to add properties to BotChat.App  `var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
            token: model.token
        });
          BotChat.App({
            directLine: { secret: model.token },
            user: { id: model.uniqueUserId, name: "Unknown" },
            botConnection: botConnection,
            bot: { id: '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotId"]' },
            resize: 'detect',
            history: model.history
          }, document.getElementById("bot"));`  and access that in messagecontroller

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677920/how-can-i-have-my-bot-start-in-a-different-dialog-depending-on-user/47680478#47680478) about the backchannel.  It sounds like what you are looking for