# How can I have my bot start in a different dialog depending on user

Tags: c#, botframework

Basically, I want to have my bot on different pages using iframes and Bot Framework Web Chat.

Depending on what page the user opens the bot, a different dialog is called.

Without Direct Line, this is as simple as adding a query parameter to api/messages and adjust the controller. But with Direct Line, I can only specify one endpoint in the portal.

I tried to change user.id in the JavaScript BotChat.App call to a different identifier and then select the correct dialog in my MessagesController based on that.
BUT: my custom id doesn't seem to be available as early as the activity "ConversationUpdate" occures where I send my welcome message. I need to send a dialog-specific welcome message though (so I need to navigate there as soon as possible and not only when the user types his first message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [backchannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel).  In your scenario you can pass a parameter from the Javascript via the back channel to set some value in `UserData`.  Now your parameter will exist in state (in this case the `IDataBag UserData`) when your user first hits the bot.

Here is a [C# sample](https://github.com/richdizz/CSharp-BotFramework-TwoWay-BackChannel) of a 2-way backchannel

another [C# sample](https://github.com/richdizz/CSharp-BotFramework-OneWay-BackChannel) using a 1 way backchannel